# WPF Change style of System ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, styles, contextmenu

Is it possible to style the System ContextMenu?
If it does, I would appreciate if you could tell me how..

**I want to change its style**, not to add items/disable items.

I am talking about this:

[image]

**EDIT:**
This is the style I am using right now (this is just an example - to see if it's possible to style the system `ContextMenu`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,5,5">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Yellow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Padding="2">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="{StaticResource DropShadowColor}" Opacity="0.60" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style is located in the App.xaml file - it affect all the `ContextMenu`s in my app except the System `ContextMenu`

Comment: Override default context menu with your own instead of customizing system context menu.

Comment: I have overridden the context menu style but it doesn't effect the system context menu

Comment: System menu impossible

Comment: @ebattulga you have an article saying it / explaining why?

Comment: It is possible. By doing exactly what Rohit said. Are you on Windows 7? Find the themes somewhere in C:Windows\..\.. and change it. Or write your own theme...

Comment: If you get system context menu handler, you can remove items and add own items with custom icons. But cannot get handler. Otherwise remove title bar and add own fake title bar.

Comment: @devhedgehog, I am on Windows 8.1 (but I guess it doesnt really matter). If I do that, it will change only in my computer... I want it generic and I prefer solution which changing external files is not included/involved.

Comment: you can take over and place your custom contextmenu with custom style defined in resources.

Comment: @devhedgehog thats what I am doing right now, and as I said above - it doesnt affect the system contextmenu. I will edit my post with the style

Comment: Post more code please, what exactly do you mean with system style? Where do you call that system style? Where do you do the right click?

Comment: @devhedgehog thats the default window's context menu... right click on any window's caption area (where the icon, title and minimize/maximize/close buttons are) and you will see it...

Comment: Ohhh, well, I found this link. Check it out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70568/An-MVVM-friendly-approach-to-adding-system-menu-en its about adding new items, but you could use this approach to set the style.